# Is it possible to store empty Component fields as well in DB while we save Component?

Tags: web8.5, broker, sdl-tridion

In our implementation of the DXA web app, most of the times we encounter scenarios where the Components are NOT having content in all the fields.

Is there a way to store these empty fields in the DB as well while saving the Components XML, as empty XML tags, so that the Component XML has all the fields in it.

Comment: Sounds very similar to https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/19796/is-it-possible-to-access-empty-component-fields-in-json-in-dxa-web-application

Comment: Or if you're talking about in CME, AFAIK - OOTB - In CME GUI default behavior it will only keep the user populated fields as Component XML, not all the fields. 

Possibility yes, if you looking to keep all the fields then you can use Event system On Save event pre-process the Component Content XML based on schema specific fields using TOM.NET API and save the Component XML.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I was thinking the same. Just wanted to confirm, if that's the only possible way to do it, as we are trying to ensure minimal usage of Event System customization in our applications.